# how to search the grid with the exact phrase?

Tags: atk4

this code uses %like% for searching. how can we define to search the exact phrase?

```
 $c->grid->addQuickSearch(array('status',"name"));
```

for example if we have (1,12,13) in the grid and we search "1" I want to show just the 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy this class to your project lib

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/QuickSearch.php#L99

and change line 116

```
$or->where($field, 'like', $v);
```

You can change name on new class and use them both - original and new.
To define which QuichSearch you want to use set class name:

```
$grid->addQuickSearch($fields,'NewQuickSearch');
```

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Grid/Advanced.php#L129